# Why is adjacent selector not working?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I learned from [here](http://sparkandshine.net/insert-images-with-captions-in-markdown/) to insert an image with captions in Markdown by

```
!["dominating_sets_example2"](http://example.com/path/dominating_sets_example2.png)
*Fig. 1: The minimum dominating set of a graph*
```

which is rendered as the following HTML,

```
<p>
    <img src="http://example.com/path/dominating_sets_example2.png" alt="dominating_sets_example2"/>
    <br>
    <em>Fig. 1: The minimum dominating set of a graph</em>
</p>
```

Then use **adjacent selectors** to customize the style for the image captions.

```
/* for image caption */
img + br + em {
    font-style: normal;
    display: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

It works.

---

Now, I add a hyperlink to the image. The HTML looks like,

```
<a href="http://example.com/path/bus.png" rel="attachment wp-att-2362" data-rel="lightbox-0" title="">
    <img src="http://example.com/path/bus.png" alt="compara_autocar_bus" width="610" height="675" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2362">
</a>
<br>
<em>
    Fig. 1: Caption here (image from <a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">here</a>)
</em>
```

I tried the following adjacent selectors, but it doesn't work.

```
a + img + br + em {
    font-style: normal;
    display: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

What is wrong with my adjacent selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your [***adjacent sibling selector***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
img + br + em
```

It  targets `<em>` elements that immediately follow a `<br>` that immediately follow an `<img>`.

In the first example, the selector works because all elements are siblings in the HTML structure:

```
<p>
    <img src="..." alt="dominating_sets_example2"/>
    <br>
    <em>Fig. 1: The minimum dominating set of a graph</em>
</p>
```

In the second example, the selector fails because the `img` is no longer a sibling of the `br` and `em`. It is now a child of `a`.

```
<p>
    <a>
       <img src="..." alt="dominating_sets_example2"/>
    </a>
    <br>
    <em>Fig. 1: The minimum dominating set of a graph</em>
</p>
```

So you need to adjust your selector to match the new structure of elements. This would work:

```
a + br + em
```

And so would this:

```
p > em   /* uses child selector to target <em> elements that are children of <p> */
```